# how to insert row(s) from xml file to sql table

Tags: sql, xml

Hello I am new in using XML file,
I tried insert a file ICD.xml to sql table
XML file format such as this

```
   <letter>
<title>#</title>
<mainTerm>
  <title>1-propanol</title>
  <cell col="2">T51.3X1</cell>
  <cell col="3">T51.3X2</cell>
  <cell col="4">T51.3X3</cell>
  <cell col="5">T51.3X4</cell>
  <cell col="6">--</cell>
  <cell col="7">--</cell>
</mainTerm>
<mainTerm>
  <title>2-propanol</title>
  <cell col="2">T51.2X1</cell>
  <cell col="3">T51.2X2</cell>
  <cell col="4">T51.2X3</cell>
  <cell col="5">T51.2X4</cell>
  <cell col="6">--</cell>
  <cell col="7">--</cell>
</mainTerm>
```

i use this code

```
Declare @xml XML

Select  @xml  = CONVERT(XML,bulkcolumn,2) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'File Path',SINGLE_BLOB) AS X

SET ARITHABORT ON 
Insert into dbo.TestXML
    (
        C1,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7
    )


Select 
    p.value('C1[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS C1,
    P.value('C2[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS C2,
    P.value('C3[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS C3,
    P.value('C4[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS C4,
    P.value('C5[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS C5,
    P.value('C6[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS C6,
    P.value('C7[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS C7,

From @xml.nodes('/letter/title') PropertyFeed(P)
```

but i have error in syntax 
can you help me and if there another way 
thnx

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: i'm using sql database and it's name (MainDB)

Comment: "sql database" is not a database. It's an expression. What **database engine** are you using (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL)? There are differences between them, and trying to answer your question means we need to know which one it is you're using. If you post a question that says "How do I fix my car?" on an auto repair site, the answer will be different for a Ferrari than it will be for a Honda; the same applies here. Please [edit] your question and provide the tag for the specific DBMS you're using. Thanks.

Comment: Other words: what database software are you using?

Comment: The syntax error is because of the comma after `C7`. You should not have a comma after the last column in the column list.

Comment: To get the values you want you need to change your nodes clause to `/letter/mainTerm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the closing element "letter"
2. Add column C2 in the INSERT statement
3. Remove the comma after the last column in the column list
4. Modify XQuery in method to nodes('/letter/mainTerm')
5. Add condition for each values in the .value method

--

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TestXML') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.TestXML
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestXML
 (
  C1 varchar(10),
  C2 varchar(10),
  C3 varchar(10),
  C4 varchar(10),
  C5 varchar(10),
  C6 varchar(10),
  C7 varchar(10)
  )

DECLARE @xml xml = 
  '<letter>
    <title>#</title>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>1-propanol</title>
      <cell col="2">T51.3X1</cell>
      <cell col="3">T51.3X2</cell>
      <cell col="4">T51.3X3</cell>
      <cell col="5">T51.3X4</cell>
      <cell col="6">--</cell>
      <cell col="7">--</cell>
    </mainTerm>
    <mainTerm>
      <title>2-propanol</title>
      <cell col="2">T51.2X1</cell>
      <cell col="3">T51.2X2</cell>
      <cell col="4">T51.2X3</cell>
      <cell col="5">T51.2X4</cell>
      <cell col="6">--</cell>
      <cell col="7">--</cell>
    </mainTerm>
   </letter>'

INSERT dbo.TestXML(C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7)
SELECT p.value('(title)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS C1,
       p.value('(cell)[@col=2][1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS C2,
       p.value('(cell)[@col=3][1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS C3,
       p.value('(cell)[@col=4][1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS C4,
       p.value('(cell)[@col=5][1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS C5,
       p.value('(cell)[@col=6][1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS C6,
       p.value('(cell)[@col=7][1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS C7
FROM @xml.nodes('/letter/mainTerm') PropertyFeed(p)


SELECT *
FROM dbo.TestXML
```

See example on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a029/1)